# XMLHttprequest Error message even in case of success

Tags: javascript, post, xmlhttprequest

This "working" script sends JSON to an external API. What it won't do correctly is log success or error in the console. 
Even if it works, it still displays me "Error" three times.
Questions:

a. Where is the error in the code that causes the error message in case of success?

*Edit: This part (a) has been answered by Suren Srapyan, I had the abc.status messed up, code below has been updated*

b. Does de XMLHttpRequest() allways run three times and therefore log the message thrice or is this caused by something else?

*Edit: This is most likely caused by an other part of the code*

```
var abc = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var url = "http://myurl";
  abc.open("POST", url, true);
  abc.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/json");
  abc.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (abc.status >= 200 && abc.status < 300) {
        console.log(abc.responseText);
        console.log("Success!!");
    } else {
      console.log("Error!");
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A value can not be `>= 200` and less than `200` at the same time. So you will always get the `Error` message. I think you need to check the `statusCode` only compare with `200`. But also be aware that you get the `status`. If you are going into `cross site` you will get `status` code set to `0`.

```js
var abc = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1';

abc.onreadystatechange = function () {
  console.log(abc.status);
  if (abc.status === 200) {
      console.log(abc.responseText);
      console.log("Success!!");
  } else {
    console.log("Error!");
  }
}

abc.open("GET", url, true);
abc.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/json");
```

Comment: Thanks for pushing me in the right direction! I chose a different solution (see working code above). Any idea about question (b)?

Comment: @Chris It is called only once. Maybe another problem is in the other parts of your code?

Comment: in that case, this question will be marked as answered, thank you for your help!